# Updating a UWP combobox at runtime

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP combobox which is bound to an itemsource in xaml code. It works as it should, however, I would like it to update as new items are added. I know in WPF we can use the refresh() method to achieve this. Is there a similar thing in UWP?

I have tried calling the loading method of the itemsource when the change is implemented but this is not achieving the expected result. Basically, a user through a text input can add an item which is then updated in a database via an update query. Just to add, the changes do show when the app is restarted but not during runtime. Any help with be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was using a List

```
List<ComboModel> model = new List<ComboModel>();
```

I changed the above to an Observable Collection

```
ObservableCollection<ComboModel> model = new ObservableCollection<ComboModel>();
```

Finally, after the user has added items using an input and the change effected in the database, I then reloaded the Combobox items source successfully.

```
Ability.ItemsSource = dbDetail.GetComboData("Ability");
```

Basically, the problem was using a List and not an Observable Collection. It appears List does not update because it does not see the change as opposed to Observable Collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.